# When status registeredOnServer on Android GCM expire?

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I got some debug message from `logcat` something like this:

```
07-20 15:38:41.007: V/GCMRegistrar(9023): Setting registeredOnServer status as true until 2012-07-27 15:38:41.014
```

When i call

```
GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);
```

I'm not sure what its mean? Should i setRegisteredOnServer again after 2012-07-27 15:38:41.014? does it necessary?
If i should call setRegisteredOnServer again, can i make longer expire time? And how i can do this?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is explained in javadoc. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/client-javadoc/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html#isRegisteredOnServer%28Context%29) for details.

> [public static boolean isRegisteredOnServer(Context context)](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/client-javadoc/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html#isRegisteredOnServer%28Context%29)
>
> Checks whether the device was successfully registered in the server
>   side, as set by [setRegisteredOnServer(Context, boolean)](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/client-javadoc/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html#setRegisteredOnServer%28Context,%20boolean%29).
>
> To avoid the scenario where the device sends the registration to the server but the
>   server loses it, this flag has an expiration date, which is
>   [DEFAULT_ON_SERVER_LIFESPAN_MS](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/client-javadoc/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html#DEFAULT_ON_SERVER_LIFESPAN_MS) by default (but can be changed by
>   [setRegisterOnServerLifespan(Context, long))](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/client-javadoc/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html#setRegisterOnServerLifespan%28Context,%20long%29).

Comment: Oops, it my false, I missed that part. Thanks.